# Flutter Navigator.of(context).pop() causes black screen on button spam

Tags: flutter

```
void signUserIn() async {

    showDialog(
      context: context,
       builder: (context) {
        return const Center(
          child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
        );
       },
    );


    try {
      await FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithEmailAndPassword(
        email: emailController.text, 
        password: passwordController.text,
      );
      //pop the loading circle
      Navigator.of(context).pop();
    } on FirebaseException catch (e) {
      //pop the loading circle
      Navigator.of(context).pop();
      if (e.code == 'user-not-found') {
        wrongEmailMessage();
      } else if (e.code == 'wrong-password') {
        wrongPasswordMessage();
      }
    }    
  }

  void wrongEmailMessage() {
      showDialog(
        context: context, 
        builder: (context) {
          return const AlertDialog(
            title: Text('Incorrect Email'),
          );
        },
      );
    }
  
  void wrongPasswordMessage() {
      showDialog(
        context: context, 
        builder: (context) {
          return const AlertDialog(
            title: Text('Incorrect Password'),
          );
        },
      );
    }
```

Using Navigator.of(context).pop(); to remove the loading circle behaves as expected when clicking my sign in button as normal, but if I spam it, it leads to a black screen. Additionally, VS warns me to not use buildcontext across async methods. Is there a way to stop the double pop or improve my usage?

I tried using Navigator.of(context).pop(); which causes a black screen on spam. I want my loading circle to disappear on auth error, not a black screen.

Answer (score 1):

On the screen when you call function **signUserIn**, first you must be sure this is [StatefullWidget](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/StatefulWidget-class.html), then you need to add a [bool](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/bool-class.html) variable to state. Let's name it **_isLoading**

```
class _PageState extends State<Page> {

  bool _isLoading = false;

  ...
}
```

Then you need to add this code to your function to handle multiple taps

```
void signUserIn() async {
 setState(() {
  _isLoading = true;
 });

 your code ...

 setState(() {
  _isLoading = false;
 });
```

In your layout, I reccomend you handle **_isLoading** variable to display **CircularProgressIndicator**

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Stack(
        children: [
          const Center(
            child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: <Widget>[
                Text(
                  'Authentication',
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          if (_isLoading)
            Container(
              color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.5),
              child: const Center(
                child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
              ),
            ),
        ],
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _isLoading signUserIn,
        tooltip: 'Sign in',
        child: const Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Now you don't need to call the pop method to close the dialog with **CircularProgressIndicator**, so you can remove that code and it will be something like that

```
void signUserIn() async {

 try {
  await FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithEmailAndPassword(
    email: emailController.text, 
    password: passwordController.text,
  );
} on FirebaseException catch (e) {
  if (e.code == 'user-not-found') {
    wrongEmailMessage();
  } else if (e.code == 'wrong-password') {
    wrongPasswordMessage();
  }
}
```

}

Well, it's really simple and easy but I think it's OK for a pet project but not for the production code.

In the best case, a button should call a state management and then just wait for another state to display. Please, read about state management, it really important part of Flutter applications.

[flutter_bloc](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_bloc)

[riverpod](https://pub.dev/packages/riverpod)